# Unable find real root for Cubic Equation in C++

Tags: c++, debugging, equation, cubic

I am writing a C++ program for finding the real root, x for a cubic equation 〖ax〗^3+〖bx〗^2+ cx+d=0  where  a≠0  and  b=0.

Unfortunately, I could not output the "test case 1 & 4" (ps. sample output provided below link). Perhaps any logic syntax in my coding? Greatly appreciated if anyone could show me the correct way to do it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    int a , b, c , d;
    double x , y;
    double interval1, interval2;
    bool stop;

    b = 0;
    x = 0;
    stop = true;

    cin >> a; 
    cin >> c;
    cin >> d;  

    interval1 = a * pow(x , 3) + b * pow(x , 2) + c * x + d;

    if (interval1 < 0){
        interval2 = interval1 *-1;
    }else{
        interval2 = interval1;
        interval1 = interval2 * -1;
    }

    while (stop=true){
        x = interval1;
        y = a * pow(x , 3) + b * pow(x , 2) + c * x + d;

        if(y>0 && y<0.001){
            break;
        }else{   
            if (x<interval2) { 
                interval1 = x + 0.000001;
            }else{
            stop = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (x==-0){
        x = 0;
    }

    if(a==0){
        cout << "NOT VALID" << endl;
    }else{
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[The sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqz7b.png)
[Pseudocode for the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9IRi.png)

Comment: I would strongly recommend styling your code better. Your indentations levels have no rhyme or reason. Your brace spacing is equally random, just like your operator spacing. Your decisions on whitespace don't make sense either. There are some other "better practice" concerns, but I'll keep this about style.

Comment: `while (stop=true)` makes an infinite loop.

Comment: [Understand and resolve compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/qx3cYeGfx). Do not ignore them.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: In general, a cubic equation is solved using complex numbers. Complex numbers were introduced for the first time due to the fact that there was simply not enough to solve some variants of the cubic equation of real numbers. So I recommend replacing `double` with `Complex` (you can create such class).

Comment: @AlexA.: [`std::complex` exists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

Comment: Why use `int` for the coefficients? That certainly won't work for case 4.

Comment: Off-Topic:  Replace `pow(x, 2)` with `(x * x)`, it's more efficient and takes less instructions.  Likewise with `pow(x, 3)`.

Comment: Reminder:  one `=` for **assignment** and two `==` for comparison, e.g. `while (stop=true)` may want to be `while (stop == true)` or `while (stop)`.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses! It means a lot to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost done. You need to improve some points.

1. Change `int a , b, c , d;` to `double a , b, c , d;`
2. Change condition `while (stop=true)` to `while (stop==true)`

I tested and it works as your example.